# What is the meaning of 3-layer NN, 300+100 hidden units?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am new to NN. I was getting my hands on MNIST Handwritten Dataset. They have specified the error percentage for every method they adopted in a tabular form.
Here is [link](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) to the page.
In NN section they have specified like :

> 3-layer NN, 300+100 hidden units
>
> 2-layer NN, 300 hidden units, mean square error

what does 3 layers mean ?
is it

`InputLayer+HiddenLayer+OutputLayer`

OR

```
InputLayer + 3 Hidden Layer+ outputLayer
```

Also what is the meaning of 300+100 hidden units. Specifing two numbers 300+100 indicates one hidden layer should contain `300 units` and next HiddenLayer should contain `100 units`.

If this what is meant then why 3 Layer NN ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input layer isn't counted in this notation, so 3 layer mean 2 hidden layers and 1 output layer. So in this case :

```
3-layer NN, 300+100 hidden units
```

means the following architecture :

```
Input layer
Hidden layer of 300 units
Hidden layer of 100 units
Output layer
```

Comment: Which is btw. a problematic and missleading notation, this is why one should always say "X **hidden** layers NN", then there is no confusion

Comment: Thankyou @TheWalkingCube